# Retrieve $http error status

Tags: angularjs

I use Angular $http GET request that respond with 401 status, as i verified with Chrome network tab.

Inside the errorCallback for this request the response.status is always -1. When i started to investigate it i found the source of -1 deeply inside angular file:

```
  var requestError = function() {
    // The response is always empty
    // See https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#request-error-steps and https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-network-error
    completeRequest(callback, -1, null, null, '');
  };
```

So, how i can retrieve the status code?

Answer (score -1):

Call it like this:

```
$http.get('/Url').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

  });
```

Comment: still got status -1 inside error callback. i'm using Angular 1.4.7

Answer (score -1):

Finally i found the reason is CROS error. when i changed API endpoint to responde with header:  Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* the problem solved and i can see the status code.